# Permanently Save Variables with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

One of my many Userforms in Excel uses file paths to locate files to copy,move,delete depending on the situation. The majority of these file locations are always in the same directory and i am looking for a permanent way to store the file paths like a configuration file or settings files so VBA will allows look in the same place.

I was thinking about adding the String paths to the hidden personal workbook and reference each cell when assigning the variable but i develop on my machine and then rollout to other PC and i won't to avoid overwriting them.

I've heard text files can be used or SaveSettings() method which i've used before.

What would be the best way to accomplish this task and is it worth doing?

Comment: look up [`ChDir()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264410(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Suppose it does the job, guess i'll not be lazy and change the path manually on each machine

Comment: Maybe try saving the string paths to the personal workbook, and also use the `Environ("COMPUTERNAME")` string to identify which PC you are on?

Answer (score 0):

If it is for all users/different pcs then I can think of two ways.

**Way 1**

Store the values in Excel Settings.

Use the `Application.DefaultFilePath` to store the path and then read from it later. For example

```
Sub StorePath()
    Application.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Temp"
End Sub

Sub GetPath()
    MsgBox Application.DefaultFilePath
End Sub
```

**Way 2**

Store the values in the registry. See this small [TUTORIAL](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?563162-Working-with-Windows-Registry-using-Visual-Basic-6-A-complete-Tutorial) I wrote couple of years ago.